# Search bar :Searching a term from a table with data fetched from Firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, searchbar

I want to add a search bar on my table fetched from firestore (the fetch operation is working ) but the search operation doesn't, in fact, I think that the problem is that the variable 'searchTerm' hasn't been read but I can't figure out exactly what's wrong as a beginner To React Js

**Update!!!** : as a result, the search bar is displayed with the table of clients stored in Cloud Firestore, when I enter a text in the search bar It returns an empty table although the written word is a firstname in the table
[Table initially rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYkUE.png)

[table after writing anything in the search bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TO0yJ.png)

**Customer.js**

> 

```js
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import { Avatar } from '@material-ui/core';
import PageTitle from "../../../../layouts/PageTitle";
import { Dropdown, Table } from "react-bootstrap";
import { fire } from "../../../../../fire";
import { firestore } from "../../../../../fire";
import { collection, query, where } from "../../../../../fire"; 
import App from "../../../../../App";

export default class Recipe extends React.Component {
   
   state = {
      searchTerm : "",
      Users: []
      
   }
 
   
      constructor(props){
      super(props);   
   }
   searchByTerm = (value) => {
      this.setState({searchTerm : value});
   }
componentDidMount() {
     firestore.collection("Users").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        let User = []
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(`${doc.id} => ${doc.data().lastn}`);
        User.push({   
        id : doc.id,
        data: doc.data()})
        });
        this.setState({Users : User})
      });  
   }    

       delete = (id) => {
         console.log(id)
         firestore.collection("Users").doc(id).delete().then(() => {
           console.log("Document successfully deleted!");
           this.props.history.push("#")
         }).catch((error) => {console.error("Error removing document: ", error);
         });
      }

 

render() {



      return (
      <Fragment>  
             
        
        <div className="col-12">
        <div className="card">
        <div className="card-header">
        <div className="input-group search-area d-lg-inline-flex d-none mr-5">
                           <input
                              type="text"
                              className="form-control"
                              placeholder="Search here"
                           />
                           <div className="input-group-append">
                              <span className="input-group-text" onChange ={(e)=>
                              {
                                 this.searchByTerm(e.target.value); 

                              }
                              }>
                                 <svg
                                    width={20}
                                    height={20}
                                    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                                    fill="none"
                                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                 >
                                    <path
                                       d="M23.7871 22.7761L17.9548 16.9437C19.5193 15.145 20.4665 12.7982 20.4665 10.2333C20.4665 4.58714 15.8741 0 10.2333 0C4.58714 0 0 4.59246 0 10.2333C0 15.8741 4.59246 20.4665 10.2333 20.4665C12.7982 20.4665 15.145 19.5193 16.9437 17.9548L22.7761 23.7871C22.9144 23.9255 23.1007 24 23.2816 24C23.4625 24 23.6488 23.9308 23.7871 23.7871C24.0639 23.5104 24.0639 23.0528 23.7871 22.7761ZM1.43149 10.2333C1.43149 5.38004 5.38004 1.43681 10.2279 1.43681C15.0812 1.43681 19.0244 5.38537 19.0244 10.2333C19.0244 15.0812 15.0812 19.035 10.2279 19.035C5.38004 19.035 1.43149 15.0865 1.43149 10.2333Z"
                                       fill="#A4A4A4"
                                    />
                                 </svg>
                              </span>
                           </div>  </div>
        <h4 className="card-title">Customer List </h4>
            </div> 
            <div className="card-body">      
            <Table responsive className="w-100">
            <div id="example_wrapper" className="dataTables_wrapper">
            <table id="example" className="display w-100 dataTable">
            <thead>
                           <tr role="row">
                                
                                   
                                    <th>Avatar</th>
                                    <th>Email</th>
                                    <th>Firstname</th>
                                    <th>Lastname</th>
                                    <th>PhoneNumber</th>
                                   
                                    {/* <th className="pl-5 width200">
                                    Billing Address
                                 </th> */}
                                 <th>Action</th>
                              
                              </tr>
                                   
                                 
                              </thead>
                              <tbody>
                                 {this.state.Users.filter( val =>{
                                    // console.log(this.state.searchTerm);
                                    if (this.state.searchTerm === ""){
                                       
                                       return val;
                                       
                                    } else if (
                                      
                                       val.email.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchTerm.toLowerCase()) ||

                                       val.firstname.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchTerm.toLowerCase())
                                    )

                                    {   
                                       return val }
                                 }).map(data => {

                                    return (
                                       <tr>
                                          <td> <Avatar className ="rounded-circle img-fluid" src={data.data.avatar}/> </td>
                                          
                                          <td>{data.data.email}</td>
                                          <td>{data.data.firstname}</td>
                                          <td>{data.data.datalastname}</td>
                                          <td>{data.data.phonenumber}</td>
                                            
                                           <td>
                                                         <div
                                                         className="btn btn-danger shadow btn-xs sharp" onClick ={this.delete.bind(this, data.id)}
                                                      >
                                                         <i className="fa fa-trash"></i> </div></td>                
                                     </tr>
                                    );

                                 })}
                              </tbody>
                           </table>
                           </div>
                        </Table>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
        
         </Fragment>
      );
   };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move the `onChange` from the `span` to the `input`:

```js
<div className="input-group search-area d-lg-inline-flex d-none mr-5">
  <input
    type="text"
    className="form-control"
    placeholder="Search here"
    onChange={(e) => {
      this.searchByTerm(e.target.value||'');
    }}
  />
  <div className="input-group-append">
    <span className="input-group-text">
      <svg
        width={20}
        height={20}
        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
        fill="none"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      >
        <path
          d="M23.7871 22.7761L17.9548 16.9437C19.5193 15.145 20.4665 12.7982 20.4665 10.2333C20.4665 4.58714 15.8741 0 10.2333 0C4.58714 0 0 4.59246 0 10.2333C0 15.8741 4.59246 20.4665 10.2333 20.4665C12.7982 20.4665 15.145 19.5193 16.9437 17.9548L22.7761 23.7871C22.9144 23.9255 23.1007 24 23.2816 24C23.4625 24 23.6488 23.9308 23.7871 23.7871C24.0639 23.5104 24.0639 23.0528 23.7871 22.7761ZM1.43149 10.2333C1.43149 5.38004 5.38004 1.43681 10.2279 1.43681C15.0812 1.43681 19.0244 5.38537 19.0244 10.2333C19.0244 15.0812 15.0812 19.035 10.2279 19.035C5.38004 19.035 1.43149 15.0865 1.43149 10.2333Z"
          fill="#A4A4A4"
        />
      </svg>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>;
```

UPDATE:
The `toLowerCase` error: Change this part of your code.

```js
const { email = "", firstname = "" } = val||{};
// console.log(this.state.searchTerm);
if (this.state.searchTerm === "") {
  return val;
} else if (
  email.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchTerm.toLowerCase()) ||
  firstname.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchTerm.toLowerCase())
) {
  return val;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I've changed But now I 'm getting an Error!                                                                                      "TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined"

Comment: I have updated the answers code. Try it with that.

Comment: Same Error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined"

Comment: I have updated the answer. That bug comes from somewhere else.

Comment: No, Unfortunately it doesn't work I think the problem is the variable val  but I can't figure out the right way to configure it

Comment: I have updated it again. Can you try it with that one.

Comment: Thanks there is some progress I've updated the post u can check out the two pictures I just added to show u the result

Comment: If the first problem is solved pls write a new question. I can't realy follow now what the next issue is :(

Comment: In fact, when I write anything in the search bar (even if the word written exists in the table) it returns nothing, and the table becomes an empty table !!